# How discovery service works in polyglot micro services architecture?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, cloud-foundry

If we build all micro services using spring boot, all micro services(@EnableEurekaClient) can be discoverable using Eureka Server(@EnableEurekaServer). if some of micro-services built using other technologies ,how discovery, load-balancing, reverse proxying(gateway) is possible in cloud(PCF,AWS etc)?

I read many blogs on web related to micro-services, I didn't get proper info this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eureka server itself has a REST api which allows you to manage it. You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations
If you use a framework or language which doesn't provide direct integration with Eureka, like Spring Boot, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You may also take advantage of `polyglot sidecar` support that enables integration of other technologies with `Eureka Server` for discovery. For example, non-JVM languages may enable sidecar by creating a Spring Boot application with `@EnableSidecar`. This effectively triggers `@EnableCircuitBreaker`, `@EnableDiscoveryClient`, and `@EnableZuulProxy` support. The  application should run on the same host as the non-JVM application. More details are provided at [this Spring document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__polyglot_support_with_sidecar.html). You may also take a look at an example implementation [here](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-cloud-sidecar-sample)